# Grand Tour rider holding two jerseys - what do they wear?

Tags: racing, tour-de-france

In the case when a grand tour rider is holding two or more jerseys, say the yellow (overall leader) and the polkadot (mountain leader), do they get to chose which they wear during the race and on the podium?

If they can chose, is there any contention if say the GC wearing yellow wins a big mountain stage and wants to rock the polkadot in the next stage?

Do all the jerseys need to be represented in each stage? E.g. If the GC leader holds the KOM and rides polkadot, does the yellow (in the case of TdF) just go unridden?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The riders don't get to choose.

The leader of a classification in a stage race must wear the jersey of the classification that they are leading. In instances where one rider is leading multiple classifications, the UCI sets the general regulation for precedence of the leaders' jerseys. Per [§2.6.018 of the UCI Road Race Regulations](https://assets.ctfassets.net/761l7gh5x5an/2qPklRk6XJyLMSKYF9Z2z4/e7b12550abe91c9ef73a961ed14b3276/2-ROA-20211101-E.pdf),

> If a rider is leading more than one classification, the order of
> priority of the distinctive jerseys shall be as follows:
>
> 1. general classification by time;
> 2. general classification by points;
> 3. general climber's classification;
> 4. others (young rider, combined, etc.); the order of priority among these other jerseys shall be set by the organiser
>
> In this situation, the organiser may require another rider next on the relevant
> classification to wear a jersey which is not being worn by the leader of that classification.
> However, if this rider must wear his world or national champion's jersey, or the leader's jersey of a UCI cup, circuit, series or classification, he shall wear that jersey.

The classification leader's jersey supersedes any "special" jersey the rider would otherwise be wearing; for instance, if the current world champion is leading the general classification by time of a stage race (yellow jersey), they would wear the yellow jersey for as long as they were leading that classification. As noted above, this does not apply to those who are the "runner up" to a rider who is leading multiple classifications.

With that in mind, the full hierarchy for jerseys in a stage race is:

1. GC (by time) leader
2. GC (by points) leader
3. Climber's classification leader
4. Additional stage race leader's jersey (if applicable; race organizer's prerogative)
5. Series leader's jersey (ie, Women's World Tour leader's jersey)
6. World champion's jersey
7. Regional champion's jersey (ie, European Champion's jersey)
8. National champion's jersey
9. Stage race classification "on loan" from the actual leader

For instance, in the last stage of the 2022 Tour de France, Jonas Vingegaard was leading the general classification by time (yellow jersey) and the general climber's classification (polka dot jersey). The yellow jersey takes precedence, so he was wearing the yellow jersey. Simon Geschke was in second place in the climber's competition, so he wore the polka dot jersey ("on loan" from Vingegaard).

However, if, in that example, Geschke happened to be the German Road Race National Champion, then he would've worn his German National Champion jersey for the final stage, instead of the climber's jersey. In that case, it's likely up to the organizer (ASO) as to whether the third place rider (Giulio Ciccone in this case) would wear the climber's jersey.

Comment: Nice; I did not manage to find that.  (My google-fu must be weak because "site:www.uci.org leaders jerseys" did not find that document.)  Props!

Comment: If you like, consider adding the regs about holders of national or world champ jerseys; I believe classification jerseys always supersede those jerseys (but WC > nat'l champ)

Comment: @WeiwenNg - done!

Answer (score 7):

The leader of the General Classification (GC) *always* wears the maillot jaune (yellow) regardless of any other jerseys they may be leading in.  Inevitably on the second day of the Tour, the fastest rider in the prologue time trial will be on top of the GC and simultaneously be the leader of the points competition.

What happens if the GC leader is also leading in any of the other rankings is that the second person in that ranking will wear the jersey.  So in stage 2 of this year's tour Wout van Aert, as second in the points competition, wore the maillot vert (green).

If the winner of the prologue is under 26, and eligible for the maillot blanc (white), they would be the leader in 3 classifications but nonetheless they would wear the maillot jaune.

I'm not sure what the relative precedence would be between the maillot vert and the maillot à pois (KOM, white with red polka dots), but I also can't really imagine a case where a single rider would have both *without* also being the GC leader.  (cf. [Eddie Merckx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_Merckx#1969:_A_victory_in_Paris_and_injury_in_Blois))

These things I know but I'm also having a really tough time tracking down an authoritative source; the classifications are not covered by the [official rules](https://storage-aso.lequipe.fr/ASO/egp/etapedutour/matrice-r-glement-edt22-uk-vd-f-24032022.pdf).

Comment: On the podium they get two sessions, first in one yersey, then in the other. (At least in the Tour de France.)

Comment: Minor correction: the maillot jaune is only on the TdF. The GC leader in the Giro wears a pink jersey and in the Vuelta it's a red jersey.

Comment: @jimchristie - in the general context of stage races, the Giro and Vuelta are the outliers in this aspect; stage races (amateur or pro) commonly use a yellow jersey to denote the GC leader.

Comment: @Ealhmund True, but the OP asked about _Grand Tour_ jerseys.